# A symplectic ball embedding into $\mathbb{C}P^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I want to show that the following map is a symplectic ball-embedding inside $\mathbb{C}P^2$. The mapping is defined for every $s<1$,
$i:B^4(s)\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}P^2$ as follows,

$$i(z_1,z_2):= \bigg[\sqrt{1-|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2}:z_1:z_2\bigg]$$
This is a map inside the chart $U_0$, where the symplectic form on the chart is defined as $\tilde{\omega}=i\partial \bar{\partial}f$ where $f(v)=log(1+|v|^2)$. So in order to show that the above embedding is symplectic, I have to show that the following map is symplectic,
\begin{align*}
\theta_k: B^4(s)&\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^2 \\
(z_1,z_2)&\mapsto \bigg(\frac{z_1}{\sqrt{1-|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2}}, \frac{z_2}{\sqrt{1-|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2}}\bigg)  
\end{align*}
which is to say that $\theta_k^*(\tilde{\omega})= \omega_0$, where $\tilde{\omega}$ is already and $\omega_0$ is the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Now for the lack of a better way, I simply started calculating by hand, and my calculations led me to the following expression:
$$\theta_k^*(\tilde{\omega})=i \partial \bar{\partial}f(\theta_k^*f)= i\partial \bar{\partial}(f\circ \theta_k)= i\bigg\{ \sum_{k=1}^2 \frac{dz_k \wedge \bar{z}_k}{(1-|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2)}+ \sum_{i,k=1}^2 \frac{z_i\bar{z}_k (dz_k\wedge d\bar{z_i}) }{(1-|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2)^2}  \bigg\}$$

and I am stuck here.

Can anyone suggest me a simpler way to do this, or tell me if I am doing something wrong here? Any help would is hugely appreciated as I have been stuck at this for days.

Comment: As far as I can tell (I’m no expert though) your calculation is correct, and I don’t think there is much further simplification. Why do you expect that $\theta_k$ is a symplectomorphism?

Comment: Well, I just found it in a paper I was reading and wanted to check the statement.